# Django global filter

Tags: python, django, filter, global

Is there a way to filter globally a Django model? We need to set a filter in a single place so that it gets applied in all queries generated by Django ORM including related objects lookups etc. Example:

```py
class A(Model):
    n = IntegerField()

class B(Model):
    a = ForeignKey(A)
```

We want to set on A a global filter id__gte=10 (static to make it simple). The filter must be then automatically applied also when doing related queries, e.g.

```py
B.objects.filter(a__n=123)  # this code cannot be modified
```

should expand somehow magically to an equivalent of

```py
B.objects.filter(a__n=123, a__id__gte=10)
```

We can change models, managers, querysets but we cannot change the code where objects are actually queried (a lot of code, third party apps, generic API).

Comment: Given you query `A.objects.all()` you want to filter `A`s with an `id` less than 10 out as well?

Comment: Yes, everywhere.

Comment: If you want it to be truly global... there's one super simple way: `A.objects.filter(id__lt=10).delete()`

Comment: I want to filter, not to delete.

Comment: @RadimBlazek Have you solved this problem already? Or is is still "impossible". I am facing exactly the same problem now - I can change all the code, but it would be much more convenient to do it this way... I hope the question will reach you.

Comment: We are using global instance of our ContextParams class https://github.com/MPASolutions/django-dal/blob/master/django_dal/params.py based on contextvars package. Those global params are used in managers etc. It does not solve the problem of related objects which have to be queried "manually" using related objects model default manager (which is using those context params).

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a view in the database with the filter and create a Django model pointing to the view?

Comment: That is exactly what we are doing now and what we would like to abandon. It is a bit clumsy to have to recreate the view whenever the filter changes and it would be nice to be able to use Python code (in case of dynamic filters).

Answer (score 0):

You should make a custom manager and modify an initial `QuerySet`. Check out [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset).

> ```
> # First, define the Manager subclass.
> class DahlBookManager(models.Manager):
>     def get_queryset(self):
>         return super().get_queryset().filter(author='Roald Dahl')
>
> # Then hook it into the Book model explicitly.
> class Book(models.Model):
>     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
>     author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
>
>     objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
>     dahl_objects = DahlBookManager() # The Dahl-specific manager.
> ```

Then you should use your custom manager (`dahl_objects`) instead of `objects` and all queries will be modified.

Or you can override `objects` manager itself

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    objects = DahlBookManager() # The Dahl-specific manager
```

Comment: 1) As I wrote, we cannot modify the code where the query is made, we cannot change A.objects.all() to A.my_objects.all(). 2) It does not get applied when doing related queries as in my example.

Comment: @RadimBlazek ok, I updated an answer. In any case, you still need to update a model.

Comment: The manager (even default) is not taken into account when doing related queries. Please see B.objects.filter(a__n=123) in my original question. If I define A.objects=MyManager(), it is ignored by B.objects.filter(a__n=123). That is the core of the question, how to get it applied everywhere.

Comment: Can you give an example how the managers for A and B should look like?